# Tensor contraction via universal property of the tensor product

Tags: differential-geometry, modules, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, contraction-operator

I'm having a little trouble with the definition of the contraction operation for tensors via the universal property of the tensor product. The construction I've found (for instance, suggested [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules#Tensor_product_of_sheaves_of_modules) and outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792230/coordinate-free-notation-for-tensor-contraction/3976713#3976713)) goes as follows: suppose we have a commutative ring $R$ (for example, the smooth real valued functions on a manifold) and an $R$-module $E$ which is finitely generated and projective (for example, the module of smooth sections of the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold), with dual $E^{*}$. Consider the tensor product

$$
\bigotimes_{i=1}^{r}E \otimes \bigotimes_{i=1}^{s}E^{*}
$$

and call $\otimes^r_s$ the corresponding canonical multilinear mapping between the cartesian product to the tensor product. To define the contraction $C^\ell_{k}$ between the $\ell$-th $E$ factor and the $k$-th $E^{*}$ factor, one defines the (suppossedly) multilinear mapping:

$$
f:\prod_{i=1}^{r}E \times \prod_{i=1}^{s}E^{*}\longrightarrow \prod_{i=1}^{r-1}E \times \prod_{i=1}^{s-1}E^{*} 
$$

$$
f:(U_1,\ldots,U_r,\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^s)\mapsto \omega^k(U_\ell)(U_1,\ldots,\widehat{U_\ell},\ldots,U_r,\omega_1,\ldots,\widehat{\omega^k},\ldots,\omega_s)
$$

where hats mean ommitted arguments, and where (I presume) the product spaces are understood to be $R$-modules through the usual construction as direct sums/products. Then by the universal property of the tensor product, there exists a unique module homomorphism

$$
h:\bigotimes_{i=1}^{r}E \otimes \bigotimes_{i=1}^{s}E^{*}\longrightarrow \prod_{i=1}^{r-1}E \times \prod_{i=1}^{s-1}E^{*}
$$

such that $f = h\circ\otimes^r_s$; then the contraction would suppossedly be defined as $C^\ell_k:= \otimes^{r-1}_{s-1}\circ h$, and the universal property should yield:

$$
C^\ell_k(U_1\otimes\cdots\otimes U_r\otimes\omega^1\otimes\cdots\otimes\omega^s) = \omega^k(U_\ell)U_1\otimes\cdots,\otimes\widehat{U_\ell}\otimes\cdots\otimes U_r\otimes\omega_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\widehat{\omega^k}\otimes\cdots\otimes\omega_s
$$

I just can't get this to work. My questions/problems are:

1. How exactly is $f$ suppossed to be multilinear? If addition and multiplication by elements of $R$ on $\prod_{i=1}^{r-1}E \times \prod_{i=1}^{s-1}E^{*}$ are defined component-wise, then it seems that $f$ would only be multilinear in the two arguments that are being contracted.
2. Even if we admit that $h$ exists and is unique, if we understand that multiplication by elements of $R$ acts componentwise, then we should have:

$$
\otimes^{r-1}_{s-1}\left(\omega^k(U_\ell)(U_1,\ldots,\widehat{U_\ell},\ldots,U_r,\omega_1,\ldots,\widehat{\omega^k},\ldots,\omega_s)\right) = \omega^k(U_\ell)^{(r-1)(s-1)}U_1\otimes\cdots,\otimes\widehat{U_\ell}\otimes\cdots\otimes U_r\otimes\omega_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\widehat{\omega^k}\otimes\cdots\otimes\omega_s
$$

since the factor $\omega^k(U_\ell)$ multiplies all the components and thus appears $(r-1)(s-1)$ times in the tensor product.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f$ should go directly to the tensor product space.
How do you multiply an element of the direct product by a scalar (element of $R$)? Well, we can do that: multiply each coordinate - that's how your question 2. possibly arose, but that's not what we want here: the scalar $\omega^k(U_\ell)$ is meant to be a single factor of the single tensor
$$U_1\otimes\cdots\otimes \widehat{U_\ell}\otimes\cdots\otimes U_r\,\otimes\,\omega_1\otimes\cdots \otimes\widehat{\omega_k}\otimes \cdots\otimes \omega_s\,.$$
As you observed, the part $\omega^k(U_\ell)$ is $R$-linear in both variables, and using this tensor, you can prove $R$-linearity of the other variables as well.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something.

Comment: I've edited the Wikipedia article I cited in my question with your correction.