# Tensor contraction and C-infinity module

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, vector-bundles, multilinear-algebra

If one defines a smooth $(r,s)$ tensor field on a differentiable manifold as a $C^{\infty}(M)$ multilinear map
$$T : (\Gamma(T^*M))^r \times (\Gamma(TM))^s \xrightarrow{\sim} C^{\infty}(M)$$
from the modules of smooth sections of the cotangent and tangent bundles respectively, how does one define contractions (in a coordinate free way)? Must an approach with tensor products be employed?

I know the idea of contraction is to take a vector field input and covector field input and let the second act on the first to multiply the tensor by a smooth function, but I'm not sure how to implement it in this picture.

Approach via tensor products: [Coordinate-free notation for tensor contraction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792230/coordinate-free-notation-for-tensor-contraction?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The answer to that post gives a coordinate free way to get a contraction *over a single vector space* in terms of the universal property of the tensor product, similar to the idea I quoted above. So this is only applicable if we consider tensors as sections of the tensor bundle and hence are able to write in some coordinate patch on $M$ in a form like
$$T = T_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu \otimes dx^\nu$$

**So my question becomes:** can one define tensor field contraction without going to a pointwise construction?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Tensor contraction *is* a pointwise operation. I think of a tensor bundle as a parameterized family of vector spaces where the parameter space is the manifold. Any linear algebra or tensor operation that can be applied to a single vector space can be applied to each fiber of vector bundle.  For me that’s easier to work with than the infinite dimensional space of sections.

Comment: Okay, this is what I was beginning to suspect. Thank you for making it clear.