# Help needed with tensors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, tensors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [An Introduction to Tensors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors)

Recently I came across the concept of `tensors` and heard it is very difficult to understand.

> Is there a tutorial to learn `tensors`?
>
> Where do you start learning them?
>
> Which field of math is a prerequisite?
>
> What are it's application?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67374/tensors-what-should-i-learn-before

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) has a nice write-up about tensors. There's also a link to an introductory reader ([see here](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/Numbers/Math/documents/Tensors_TM2002211716.pdf)).