# What does $[\mathbf{a}]_\times\mathbf{b}$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, vectors

The left means $A$ cross $B$. What does the right mean?

$$\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}=[\mathbf{a}]_\times\mathbf{b}$$

It came from the GitHub post ["How to derive essential matrix from camera projection matrices?"](http://simbaforrest.github.io/blog/2016/12/21/derive-essential-matrix-from-camera-projection-matrices.html) by Chen Feng (simbaforrest).

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication)

Comment: Somewhat related question I asked: [Is there a 'geometric' version of this derivation of the vorticity equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831115/is-there-a-geometric-version-of-this-derivation-of-the-vorticity-equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above transforms a vector function into a linear algebra matrix product

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_x \\ a_y \\ a_z \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} b_x \\ b_y \\ b_z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -a_z & a_y \\ a_z & 0 & -a_x \\ -a_y & a_x & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} b_x \\ b_y \\ b_z \end{pmatrix} $$

My personal preference is to include the cross operator inside the brackets, such as

$$ \boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b} = [ \boldsymbol{a} \times] \boldsymbol{b} $$

because the $[\boldsymbol{a}\times]$ stands on its own and it reminds me of a matrix.

Alternative notation I have seen is the tilde on top, such as $ \boldsymbol{\tilde{a}} \boldsymbol{b}$, but again this is not clear enough IMHO.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) for the conversion of the vector cross product to matrix multiplication.

Comment: see updates to anser.