# Relationship between a tensor and the tensor product

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I am trying to wrap my head around what exactly a tensor is. I am familiar with the notion of a tensor product, both the basis-dependent and basis-independent definitions, and there seems to be a link between them and tensors. I have seen some sources define tensors as elements of a tensor product, but there seems to be more to it than this. Can a tensor be defined in terms of tensor products, and if so, what else can be said?

I have already gone through the following questions:

- [What is the difference between tensors and tensor products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97764/what-is-the-difference-between-tensors-and-tensor-products)
- [What, Exactly, Is a Tensor?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657494/what-exactly-is-a-tensor)

but my confusion still remains.

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ are modules, then a tensor is an element of the the tensor product $V\otimes W$. More generally, a tensor is an element of a tensor product of modules.

Comment: @morrowmh That is really all there is to it?

Comment: Note that [a simple tensor](https://planetmath.org/simpletensor) is an element of $V\otimes W$ of the form $v\otimes w$ where $v\in V, w\in W$.  Not all tensors are simple tensors, but they are always linear combinations of simple tensors.  See [tensor rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_(intrinsic_definition)#Tensor_rank) for more insights.

Comment: @CBBAM In its most abstract form, yes. You have elements of $V$ and elements of $W$, and you want to multiply them. The tensor product $V\otimes W$ gives you a context in which you can do this.

Comment: Have you looked at other posts on this site like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors)?

Comment: @hardmath So would it be correct to say a tensor is to a tensor product what a vector is to a vector space?

Comment: @blargoner I will take a look at this, thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3942678/mathematical-properties-of-rank-n-tensors-where-n2/3947326#3947326

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** To a *mathematician*, a tensor is just an element of a tensor product. As you ask in the comments, it is correct to say that a tensor is to a tensor product what a vector is to a vector space.

**Medium answer:** A tremendous amount of confusion here is caused by the fact that the word "tensor" has (at least) *five* different meanings which are rarely distinguished, and different communities of practitioners (e.g. mathematicians vs. physicists) default to different ones. Here they are:

1. A tensor is an element of a tensor product.
2. A tensor of type $(m, n)$ *relative to* a (usually finite-dimensional) vector space $V$ is an element of the tensor product $V^{\otimes n} \otimes (V^{\ast})^{\otimes m}$.
3. A tensor is a multidimensional array of numbers (a [hypermatrix](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypermatrix.html)).
4. A tensor is a [tensor field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_field) (e.g. the [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) or the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor)).
5. A tensor is an object which transforms in a certain way under change of coordinates.

These concepts are of course related (2 is a special case of 1, 3 is how you represent a tensor in sense either 1 or 2 using a choice of basis, 5 is equivalent to either 2 or 4 depending on context, 4 is a generalization of 2) but they are not *the same* and much confusion results from not carefully distinguishing them.

Additionally sense 2 is more sophisticated than it appears, because we have the freedom to interpret a tensor of type $(m, n)$ as a function between tensor products in $2^{m+n}$ different ways. For example, a tensor of type $(1, 1)$ can be thought of as any of

- an element of $V \otimes V^{\ast}$,
- a linear map $V \to V$,
- a linear map $V^{\ast} \to V^{\ast}$, or
- a linear functional $V^{\ast} \otimes V \to K$ where $K$ is the underlying field

and any of these representations may be appropriate depending on context.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew the term is used so ambiguously, that helps explain part of my confusion.