# What is tensor, really?

Tags: soft-question, education, tensors

How can one understands the definition of *tensor* from the purely formal point of view?

To what abstract structure this concept can be generalized?

Comment: It depends upon what your base generality is. Monoidal categories are a vast generalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors