# How can we visualize a tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to visualize a tensor in the analogous way that we visualize a vector. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Differences between a matrix and a tensor](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412423/differences-between-a-matrix-and-a-tensor) **AND** [Are there any differences between tensors and multidimensional arrays?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134809/are-there-any-differences-between-tensors-and-multidimensional-arrays) **AND** [An Introduction to Tensors](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors)

Comment: I don't know that there's a good way to do this in that kind of generality. For instance, how do you visualize an arbitrary matrix?