# Can all rank two tensors be represented as matrices?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I’m curious about wether every Tensor of second order can be represented as a matrix.
The only possibilities are (to my understanding, correct me if i’m wrong):
$$\mathcal{T}^{(2;0)}= \mathbf{V\otimes V}$$
$$\mathcal{T}^{(1;1)}= \mathbf{V\otimes V^*}$$
$$\mathcal{T}^{(0;2)}= \mathbf{V^* \otimes V^*}$$
Can all these be represented as $n\times n$ matrices? If so, i would like to know if there is a difference between all these matrices.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When $\mathbf{V}$ is a finite dimensional vector space then its dual is a vector space of the same dimension. Then follow hint: [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: See also [Are there any differences between tensors and multidimensional arrays?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134809/are-there-any-differences-between-tensors-and-multidimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At risk of reading too much into the question:

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space, then upon fixing a basis of $V$ (which determines a unique dual basis of $V^{*}$) every real-valued $2$-tensor $T$ is uniquely determined by a doubly-indexed set of real coefficients, namely the values of $T$ on appropriate basis and/or dual basis vectors. Since any such collection may be written as a matrix, "yes (in this sense)."

That said, a $2$-tensor is not just a set of components in a specific basis, it's a bilinear function, or a set of components in an *arbitrary basis*. A matrix alone does not capture that. Concretely, a matrix of components alone does not tell us how the components *transform under change of basis*. That transformation law is an essential datum.

Tangential anecdote: Some years back there was a question on Math.SE about the intersection form of a particular simply-connected $4$-manifold, and an apparent contradiction between using two particular bases for two-dimensonal homology. The resolution was that an intersection form, contrary to OP's understandable matrix-based habit, does not transform by similarity like a linear transformation (tensor in $V^{*} \otimes V$), but like a quadratic form (tensor in $V^{*} \otimes V^{*}$).

Comment: Ok, i get the transformation part now, and no, the thing you adress in your question is exactly what i mean.  Maybe can i get an example of a $\mathbf{V \otimes V\otimes V^*\rightarrow V}$ contraction using matrices?

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind by way of an example, but a contraction refers to taking the trace of an endomorphism, which for a matrix is just the sum of the diagonal entries (which might themselves be tensors).

Comment: Ok. I think i get it now. Didn’t have into account that the underlying vector spaces $\{\mathbf{V;V^*}\}$ could also be tensors. Thanks!