# How to reconcile these two definitions of tensors

Tags: tensors

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC98KfiGAOk&index=14&list=PLlXfTHzgMRULkodlIEqfgTS-H1AY_bNtq) lecture series a definition of a tensor is given roughly as follows:

> ***(Definition 1)***:
>
> [we] define tensors as variants that transform from one coordinate
>   system to another by a very special rule.
>   A variant $T_i$ is called a covariant tensor if its values $T_i$ and $T_{i'}$  in the coordinate systems $Z^i$ and $Z^{i'}$ are related by
>   $$T_{i'}=  T_i J^i_{i'}$$
>   *[then a similar definition for a contravariant tensor]*

How is this reconciled with the definition that seems to me to be much more general:

> **(Definition 2):**
>
> Given vector space $V$, a tensor is a multilinear map $V^* \times
>  ... \times V^*\times V \times ... \times V \to \mathbf{R}$

It seems to me that the first definition is extremely restrictive compared to the second one.
**Aren't there other types of linear transformations that tensors can do (acc. to the second definition) that are not specifically transformations between coordinate systems?** (even if you ignore the fact that the first definition is restrictive in terms of the dimensions of the tensor).

**What explains this difference?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the first one is more restrictive, since it's only the definition of a $(0,1)$-tensor (corresponding to a linear map $T\colon V \to \mathbf{R}$ in terms of the second definition).

Comment: Thank you. I didnt even think of that, but I was thinking also of another point. Namely the fact that the first definition specifically demands that a tensor has to transform between coordinate systems. Aren't there other types of linear transformations that tensors can do that are not specifically transformations between coordinate systems?

Comment: By the way, don't you mean a (1,1) tensor?

Comment: No, $T_i$ has no (0) upper indices and one (1) lower index, hence type (0,1).

Comment: Regarding your first question, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. But see here for more info about different ways of thinking about tensors: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors