# Generalization of matrix for multilinear maps

Tags: matrices, multilinear-algebra

Consider finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces $V, W, Q$, where $V$ has basis $\{ e_{1}, \ldots, e_{n} \}$, the space $W$ has basis $\{ f_{1}, \ldots, f_{m} \}$, and $Q$ has basis $\{ h_{1}, \ldots, h_{\ell} \}$. Then we can canonically correspond any linear maps $A: V \to W, B : W \to Q$ to matrices
\begin{align*}
M(A) & = [\pi_{f_i}(e_{j})]_{i, j} , \\
M(B) & = [ \pi_{h_{i}}(f_{j}) ]_{i, j} 
\end{align*}
in such a way that $M(BA) = M(B) M(A)$, where multiplication of matrices is fairly intuitively defined.

My question is: suppose we have a multilinear map $F : V_{1} \times \cdots \times V_{s} \to W$ and all the vector spaces $V_{i}, W$ have distinguished bases; then in the same way that we can define a matrix corresponding to linear map $V \to W$ as a $\dim(W) \times \dim(V)$-tuple of scalars, can we define a $\dim(W) \times \dim(V_{s}) \times \cdots \times \dim (V_{1})$-tuple *and* a reasonably intuitive "multiplication" of these "multi-matrices" that corresponds with composition?

Comment: Yes, they're called tensors.

Comment: Some of the tools of tensor algebra are very useful here, though being a "tensor" often includes other properties involving coordinate transformations which may not be needed. The [Einstein Summation Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) is a common choice to compactly represent tensor equations.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors