# I know about dot and cross products but what is a tensor product?

Tags: matrices, definition, tensor-products

I have done engineering maths during university days. However, that was a few years ago. I am reading about fast 2D DCT algorithms and came across a term "tensor product". I think tensors are something that einstien used in his relativity theory Maths somewhere maybe.

Anyway, I know about dot and cross products, but in simple words, what is a tensor product?

Comment: Do you mean "tensor product"?

Comment: HINT: http://google.com/ Now search for "tensor product".

Comment: It’s also sometimes called the “outer product.”

Comment: or [wikipeadea it for a rough introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)

Comment: @Masacroso that's not a particularly helpful comment.  Searching for "tensor product" leads to at least 4 different ideas of what a "tensor" or "tensor product" might be, each which are related, but superficially very different.

Comment: @quantum231 if you want a useful answer, you're going to need to provide a more exact context.  Could you link to where you came across the term?

Comment: Ok, I am reading notes on an implementation of discrete cosine transform for 2D DCT. It first appeared in a paper by Ephreim Feig in "IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON SIGNAL PROCESSING, VOL. 40. NO. 9. SEPTEMBER 1992". I am reading its description from book JPEG still image data compression standard by Willam and Joan (1993). The concept of tensor product appears in it.

Comment: Perhaps useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors

Comment: thanks, at this stage I have decied to just go with the signal flow graph and not try to learn the complete theory of tensor products. I am however, going to read this link. so thanks.